# Use OSM Map in SUMO

Tags: openstreetmap, simulator, network-traffic

I want to export a Munich map from OSM for SUMO Simulator. I've managed to download such a map from bbbike.de(472MB), but when I'm converting it to .net.xml with netconvert I'm getting a lot of warnnings and the simulator cannot import the map ("Loading error"). Do you have any idea how can I convert correctly the map (or do you think it is because the big volume of the file?), or where could I get such a map(in a properly sumo format = xml, I acctualy need just the highways, I've tried to select just highways with osmosis but I have the same problem in the end)?

Comment: Did you tried to do the processing using the eWorld GUI already? http://eworld.sf.net
Please use extracts from http://planet.osm.org and split it using osmosis tool and munich boundingbox.

Comment: thx but i found my problem. the simulator SUMO can not suport such big data volum

Comment: Thats odd, but if filtering for highway=* fixes your problem it's fine. I added it to the OSM page http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simulators#Traffic

Comment: it's because the first time i've tried to import 369 MB an it was to much for the simulator, now i'm importing just a smaller part of the map :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok to summarize our experience and to close this question :)

SUMO has problems with **parsing big full OSM files**. So you need to cut the area and filter for highways with osmosis:

Get the state of bavaria or of the surrounding http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/bayern/oberbayern.html

```
osmosis --read-pbf ./oberbayern-latest.osm.pbf --bounding-box top=48.3298 left=11.2699 bottom=48.0460 right=11.8948 --write-xml ./munich.xml

osmosis --read-xml ./munich.xml --tf accept-ways highway=* --used-node --write-xml ./munich_streets.xml
```

This can be loaded to SUMO, esp. with the [eWorld GUI](http://eworld.sf.net).

Comment: Im trying the same now and im wondering what this osmosis command is? im totally new to it and its not part of sumo right? ist it the eWorld project?!

Comment: With a simple search at google, you would find out that this is a general OSM data processor: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis

Comment: Thanks ;) if you google osmosis you really find a lot of stuff but takes a while to find that software. i googled it with the sumo context and didnt really find anything and forgot about the osm context sorry. Anyways thank you!